# Remove / disable selected option[selected from first dropdown] from second dropdown on clicking add button php

Tags: php, jquery

index.php

```
<?php
//index.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");
function fill_unit_select_box($connect)
{ 
 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_unit ORDER BY unit_name ASC";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row["unit_name"].'">'.$row["unit_name"].'</option>';
 }
 return $output;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Add Remove Select Box Fields Dynamically using jQuery Ajax in PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <h3 align="center">Add Remove Select Box Fields Dynamically using jQuery Ajax in PHP</h3>
   <br />
   <h4 align="center">Enter Item Details</h4>
   <br />
   <form method="post" id="insert_form">
    <div class="table-repsonsive">
     <span id="error"></span>
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
      <tr>
       <th>Enter Item Name</th>
       <th>Enter Quantity</th>
       <th>Select Unit</th>
       <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_quantity[]" class="form-control item_quantity" /></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="">Select Unit</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
  $('#item_table').append(html);
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });

 $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var error = '';
  $('.item_name').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Enter Item Name at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.item_quantity').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Enter Item Quantity at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.item_unit').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Select Unit at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  if(error == '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
     if(data == 'ok')
     {
      $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>');
     }
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
  }
 });

});
</script>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
//insert.php;

if(isset($_POST["item_name"]))
{
 $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");
 $order_id = uniqid();
 for($count = 0; $count < count($_POST["item_name"]); $count++)
 {  
  $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_order_items 
  (order_id, item_name, item_quantity, item_unit) 
  VALUES (:order_id, :item_name, :item_quantity, :item_unit)
  ";
  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':order_id'   => $order_id,
    ':item_name'  => $_POST["item_name"][$count], 
    ':item_quantity' => $_POST["item_quantity"][$count], 
    ':item_unit'  => $_POST["item_unit"][$count]
   )
  );
 }
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 if(isset($result))
 {
  echo 'ok';
 }
}
?>
```

[image: This picture shows the output of the code]

What I need is:

I don't want to show `bags` option selected in the first row inside the `Select Unit` dropdown of the second row.

That is, I want the user to select only one option from the `Select Unit` dropdown. The selection of the same option from the `Select unit` dropdown must be restricted.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at jquery fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/fyxog73t/3/

**HTML Code**:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">1st Row</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select id="select_1">
      <option value="">Choose</option>
      <option value="a">A</option>
      <option value="b">B</option>
      <option value="c">C</option>
      <option value="d">D</option>
      <option value="e">E</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">2st Row</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select id="select_2">
      <option value="">Choose</option>
      <option value="a">A</option>
      <option value="b">B</option>
      <option value="c">C</option>
      <option value="d">D</option>
      <option value="e">E</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">3st Row</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select id="select_3">
      <option value="">Choose</option>
      <option value="a">A</option>
      <option value="b">B</option>
      <option value="c">C</option>
      <option value="d">D</option>
      <option value="e">E</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS Code**:

```
$(document).on('change', '[id^="select_"]', function(){
    var dropdown_value = $(this).val();
    var dropdown_id = $(this).attr('id');
  // code to update options from other dropdowns excluding currently selected dropdown
    if(dropdown_value != "") {
    $('[id^="select_"]:not([id="'+dropdown_id+'"])').find("option[value='"+dropdown_value+"']").attr('disabled', true);
    }

  // code to check, if any disabled option is present with it's value not present in other dropdown as selected option. If so then removing disabled option for that dropdown
    $('[id^="select_"]:not([id="'+dropdown_id+'"])').find("option[value!='"+dropdown_value+"']:disabled").each(function(){
        dropdown_value = $(this).val();
        dropdown_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    if($('[id^="select_"]:not([id="'+dropdown_id+'"])').find("option[value='"+dropdown_value+"']:selected").length == 0) {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Had used below steps to achieve the required output:

1) On change method written for each dropdown.
2) In that on change method, disabling other dropdown's option whose value is same as selected option from current dropdown.
3) Then checked, is their any disabled option in other dropdown's(excluding currently selected dropdown). Checking whether that disabled value is present as selected value in other dropdown's or not. If not selected then remove it's disabled attribute.